# Bind list as a parameter in Python ibm_db WHERE IN condition

Tags: python, db2

any way I can use Python list to bind to WHERE IN parameter in ibm_db?

Basically something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE FILE_NAME IN (?)"
stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)
imb_db.bind_param(stmt, 1, ['first.txt', 'second.txt'])
```

but this doesn't work.. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterizing `in` values is a common problem across different drivers and `python-ibmdb` is no exception. You could not directly parameterize a list of values per placeholder.

You would have to dynamically define the desired number of placeholders and then bind them. Something along these lines:

```
values = ['first.txt', 'second.txt']

placeholders = ",".join("?" for _ in values)
sql = """
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE FILE_NAME IN ({placeholders)""".format(placeholders=placeholders)

stmt = ibm_db.prepare(conn, sql)

for index, value in enumerate(values):
    imb_db.bind_param(stmt, index, value)
```